# Left Join on large dataset

Tags: sqlite

I have a large table with over 140 million of rows (basically from all brazilian investment funds shares organized by the enterprise official number (CNPJ) that I would like to left join with a table that has the names of the funds and their cnpj (around 26k of rows).

I have tried this:

```
INSERT INTO dataset_fundos
SELECT 
inf_diario_fi.CNPJ_FUNDO,
cadastro_fundos.DENOM_SOCIAL,
cadastro_fundos.CLASSE,
inf_diario_fi.DT_COMPTC,
inf_diario_fi.VL_TOTAL,
inf_diario_fi.VL_QUOTA,
inf_diario_fi.VL_PATRIM_LIQ,
inf_diario_fi.CAPTC_DIA,
inf_diario_fi.RESG_DIA,
inf_diario_fi.NR_COTST 
FROM inf_diario_fi 
LEFT JOIN cadastro_fundos ON inf_diario_fi.CNPJ_FUNDO = cadastro_fundos.CNPJ_FUNDO;
```

However I have been running this join for over 3 days and it has not finished. I tried indexing the CNPJ column from both tables, but still another 3 days and it could not finish the dask (I interrupted it since it was taking so long). I read on some topics people joining 50 million of rows and complaining that it takes more than 3 mins, so I guess I am doing something wrong here. Sorry if it is a basic question, I am new to SQL and I adapted this code from other codes found here on stackexchange, so I guess it probably isn't optimal.

Comment: you have any indexes on this tables?

Comment: yes, I indexed the tables by the cnpj column

Comment: you try execute query without insert?

Comment: wow, without insert it ran almost instantaneously, but then how can I save this new table in a new database now?

Comment: probably you have many indexes/triggers/cheks in dataset_fundos - try save data to new table